# Lambda SQL Query / Manipulate String At Query Or After Result

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, lambda

I'm using C#, EF5, and Lambda style queries against SQL.

I have the usual scenario of binding data to gridviews. Some of the results for my columns may be too long (character count) and so I only want to display the first 'n' characters. Let's say 10 characters for this example. When I truncate a result, I'd like to indicate this by appending "...". So, let's say the following last names are returned:

> Mercer, Smith, Garcia-Jones

I'd like them to be returned like this:

> Mercer, Smith, Garcia-Jon...

I was doing something like this:

```
using (var context = new iaiEntityConnection())
{
    var query = context.applications.Where(c => c.id == applicationPrimaryKey);               
    var results = query.ToList();

    foreach (var row in results)
    {
        if (row.employerName.Length > 10)
        {
            row.employerName = row.employerName.Substring(0, Math.Min(10, row.employerName.ToString().Length)) + "...";
        }

        if (row.jobTitle.Length > 10)
        {
            row.jobTitle = row.jobTitle.Substring(0, Math.Min(10, row.jobTitle.ToString().Length)) + "...";
        }
    }

    gdvWorkHistory.DataSource = results;
    gdvWorkHistory.DataBind();
```

However, if I change my query to select specific columns like this:

```
var query2 = context.applications.Select(c => new
{
    c.id,
    c.applicationCode,
    c.applicationCategoryLong,
    c.applicationType,
    c.renew_certification.PGI_nameLast,
    c.renew_certification.PGI_nameFirst,
    c.renew_certification.PAI_homeCity,
    c.renew_certification.PAI_homeState,
    c.reviewStatusUser,
    c.dateTimeSubmittedByUser
})
```

The result appears to become read-only if specific columns are selected, and I really should be selecting just the columns I need. I'm losing my ability to edit the result set.
So, I'm rethinking the entire approach. There must be away to select the first 'n' characters on select, right? Is there anyway to append the "..." if the length is > 10 on select? That seems trickier. Also, I guess I could parse through the gridview after bind and make this adjustment. Or, perhaps there is a way to maintain my ability to edit the result set when selecting specific columns?

I welcome your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: So you want the result to be read/write, AND you want to cut off the names if they are too long? How will that not delete data in your DB?

Comment: I wouldn't call context.savechanges() on the result set which is required to update the DB. I only want to update the results for binding to the gridview. Admittedly, there is probably a more graceful way to handle this. The technique I posted works fine if I don't select specific columns. No problems with the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx)

Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of read-only properties into a single object without having to explicitly define a type first.

So you would have to define a class and select into that if you want read write capability.

e.g.

```
public class MyClass {
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string applicationCode {get; set; }
  // rest of property defintions.
}

var query2 = context.applications.Select(c => new MyClass {
                  id = c.id,
                  applicationCode = c.applicationCode,
                  // Rest of assignments
             };
```

As to just providing 10 character limit with `...` appended.  I'm going to assume you mean on the applicationcategoryLog field but you can use the same logic on other fields.

```
var query2 = context.applications.Select(c => new
{
    c.id,
    c.applicationCode,
    applicationCategoryLong = (c.applicationCategoryLong ?? string.Empty).Length <= 10 ?
                                 c.applicationCategoryLong : 
                                 c.applicationCategoryLong.Substring(0,10) + "...",
    c.applicationType,
    c.renew_certification.PGI_nameLast,
    c.renew_certification.PGI_nameFirst,
    c.renew_certification.PAI_homeCity,
    c.renew_certification.PAI_homeState,
    c.reviewStatusUser,
    c.dateTimeSubmittedByUser
})
```

Comment: The logic provided in the 2nd snippet works perfectly. I really need to learn this. What topic would I search to read up on this? Let me take a stab at translating the conversion on "applicationCategoryLong".  
***if c.applicationCategoryLong is null then use String.Empty. If the length of this is <= 10 just use this value...if not, use the first 10 characters starting at character 0 and append "..."

Comment: @Matt close, It only uses the string.Empty for the comparison check, therefore if c.applicationCategoryLong is null then the resulting value will be null.  Its just to prevent a null reference exception occurring on the length check.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the ?? and the : are specific to C# as opposed to something particular to EF and/or database queries. Very helpful to a noob so he doesn't do things the hard(er) way. :)

Comment: @matt No problems `??` is equivalent to `ISNULL` in TSql and `condition ? true : false` is equivalent to `case when condition then true else false end` Tsql construct.